# Store additional keys in dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to figure out how can we add additional information to python dictionary.

For example as per standard way, we can have `["python":14, "Programming":15]`.
Now I may want to store it as `["d1":"python":14, "d1":"Programming":15]` as 1 set.

How can we achieve  this?

Comment: why are you repeating `d1`?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham: That's my requirement. I might have another one like ["d2":"python":14, "d2":"Programming":15,"d1":"python":14, "d1":"Programming":15] for example

Comment: Do you mean a nested dict of dicts?

Comment: You have a requirement to create an unusable data structure?

Comment: Can you please use proper Python terms? You said *'Now I may want to store it as ["d1":"python":14, "d1":"Programming":15] as 1 set'* ; that's not a set; it's not a list either like your [brackets] suggest; you're actually asking for a dict. Inside a dict. i.e. a *nested dict*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store dicts of dicts using d1, d2,d3 etc.. as the keys:

```
d={"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15},"d2":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}
```

Just access each sub dict to get what you need:

```
In [11]: d = {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15},"d2":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}    
In [12]: d["d1"]
Out[12]: {'Programming': 15, 'python': 14} # d1's value is a dict
In [13]: d["d2"]
Out[13]: {'Programming': 15, 'python': 14} # d2's value is a dict
In [14]: d["d2"]["python"]
Out[14]: 14    
In [14]: d["d2"]["Programming"]
Out[14]: 15
```

You can also nest further as per your comment:

```
In [16]: d={"p1": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}, "p2": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}} }

In [17]: d["p2"]["d1"]
Out[17]: {'Programming': 15, 'python': 14}
In [18]: d["p2"]["d1"]["python"]
Out[18]: 14
```

Comment: Can that be looped further like:

`d={"p1": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}, 
     "p2": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}` and so on?

If I have to read it, how do I do that? like i want to check d1 of python

Comment: @Dinakar yes no problem, the only thing you cannot do is have repeating keys

Comment: If I have to read it, how do I do that? like i want to check d1 of python ?

Comment: @Dinakar, added an example

Comment: <br> and if I have to access all the values of d1, then I just give:</br>

<br>**In:** `d[d1]`</br>

<br>Please correct me if I am wrong</br>

Comment: In the first example yes once you pass the string `"d1"`.

Comment: Ok Will it work if `d={"p1": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}, "p2": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}} }`

Comment: yes no problem, you can have duplicate keys in a dict of dicts just not duplicate keys in the same dict, each nested dict is it's own dict.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to have multiple different keys map to the same value, so that

```
    my_dict["d1"] = 14 
    my_dict["python"] = 14
```

Dict objects support that easily, you just need to define

```
    my_dict = {"d1":14,"python":14,"d2":15}
```

If on the other hand you want a single key to be able to map to multiple values, you could try Padraic's answer or you could try

```
    my_dict = {"d1":("python",14)}
```

though that might not be quite what you're looking for if you want a truly nested data structure.