# Comparing List to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list:

`['Dinakar','Indiana','Python','Python'].` This is just for example.

Now I have dictionary:
`{"p1":("Dinakar":1, "Python":1)}`. Note there is no Indiana.

Now I want traverse through the dictionary and check if all items that are in list are there in dict. If it is not there, I would add. If it is there, I would add the count.

so in the end it would look like:

```
{"p1":("Dinakar":1, "Python":2, 'Indiana':1)}
```

It is important to note that, my dict would look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518331/store-additional-keys-in-dict-of-dicts):

Can you please give an example on how we can do it? I am new to collections

Comment: OK, so where is your code?

Comment: You're describing `collections.Counter`

Comment: define `add it to dictionary`. A dictionary entry has a key and a value.

Comment: can you please give an example on how we can do it? I am new to collections

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you comparing the list to the dictionary keys or the dictionary values? Do you have some example I/O?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - My dict would look like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518331/store-additional-keys-in-dict-of-dicts

Comment: I think you should add that to your question. Pretty vital information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a']
counter = Counter()
counter.update(items)
counter.update(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'bar'])
print(counter)
```

prints

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 2, 'foo': 1})
```

To get a bare dictionary, just use `dict()`:

```
bare_dict(dict(counter))
print(bare_dict)
```

prints

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 2, 'foo': 1}
```

Comment: @Anntti How can I achieve a dict similar to `{"p1":("Dinakar":1, "Python":2, 'Indiana':1)}`. Please note I edited my question

Comment: Also how can i get rid of `Counter` in:

`Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 2, 'foo': 1})`